# How to merge multiple SQL Server DBs to one central DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, merge-replication

I am working on 25 identical DBs (SQL Server 2014) installed in 25 Branches. I need to merge the data of these DBs into one central DB, daily.I tested Replication (merge) method. As my servers are located in a LAN network which is not domain, I encountered a problem to setup the related agent needed for replication. How I can solve the problem?

Comment: What problem? Help us help you by adding more details, error messages, what exactly you've tried, etc.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create an ETL process to handle to daily migrations of data from source to target. SSIS may be a good option for this, but that's based on the minimal info you've provided. I guess there could be more to it.

Comment: You need to provide more details on the problem. While offering better security and manageability, domain accounts are not required. Without details on the exact issues encountered, not much we can do.